# Use memcached with FOSOAuthServerBundle in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine, memcached, symfony-2.5

I'm developing a REST API in Symfony with FOSOAuthServerBundle. I use the cache (memcache) in my repositories with createQueryBuilder. I wonder if it is possible to cache queries that are made to Table access_token whenever a request is for my API.

Thanks